# Dynamic dependent field with entity reference and organic groups

Tags: views, organic-groups

I created a node type "friendly match". In this node type I got a field "club" that is an entity reference/ og reference to the "club" organic groups of the current user.

The second field named "team" should display all "team" organic groups of the club selected in the first field.

Another user gave me a hint for this module https://www.drupal.org/project/ddf

This module should allow to pass an argument from the club field to the team field. The team has use mode "views: filter by an entity reference view with dynamic arguments".

It seems that I also have to define some contextual filter in the view but I just can't figure out what filter I need to apply.

A user posted a example of the way to use the module https://www.drupal.org/node/2095179#comment-8425253

Problem is I cant adapt it to my needs. The second field always show all teams the user belongs to not just the teams of the selected club.

It would be a great help if someone could give me a hint to proceed.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to implement something like this

```
Field "Club"    Field "Team"
Club A          Team A1
                Team A2
Club B          Team B1
                Team B2
```

So i think you have to create a **club entity reference field** in **team OG** group content type. Then create the entity reference view collecting the content type: "team OG" type, contextual filter club field, and relationship referenced entity.

i'll update my answer as soon i document the steps well :-)